# Change password validation in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want my password field to accept empty string. I am using database first approach and I have changed the definition of `AspNetUsers` table to allow Null for `PasswordHash`. But during Register It says `password must be 6 characters`. How can I remove this validation. My project does not contain `IdentityConfig.cs` class. I have recently updated Identity to 2.2.1. I am using MVC.

**Update**

I have written this function in `AccountController`.

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<JsonResult> RegisterUser(string email, string password = "")
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
                return Json("Done", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json("Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

I get validation error in `result` variable.

Comment: Do you see `AccountViewModel` class in Models folder?

Comment: I am not using any ViewModel.

Comment: So how your tables got generated? I mean when you create a project you must have selected individual user authentication right?

Comment: yes am just using bootstrap modal on every page for login/register. I have updated question. Please have a look.

Comment: If you have selected **Individual User Authentication** then all those model classes gets generated for you.. Show the view otherwise..

Comment: Ok I have seen `AccountViewModel`. But I am not using this viewModel. I just have a email input filed in my view and when user inputs email i submit it to function `RegisterUser` which is defined in question.

Comment: That's fine but if you use `@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password..` in your `view` to display `textbox` for `password` then it is binding to model in `AccountViewModel`.. That's why I said show the voew///

Comment: yeah In question I have mentioned that I got validation error  in `result` variable.

Comment: which `result` variable?

Comment: variable used in function `RegisterUser` defined in question

Comment: Can you show how you created view?

Comment: My view is `<input type="email" data-bind="value:email" /> <button data-bind="click:submitEmail">Submit</button>` . Hope it will not help :P

Answer (score 2):

If you look at: \App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs, in the "Create" method you see, RequiredLength = 6 and you need to modify this:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6, //This is the validation you need to modify.
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

...

Hope this help you...

Comment: I have mentioned in quesiton. "My project does not contain `IdentityConfig.cs` class"

Comment: @IrfanWattoo Yes I got it. But in that case what is the type of UserManager in your code? If its type is: "ApplicationUserManager", then can you F12 and see where it is defined?

Comment: Step Into does not work on that line instead it shows a popup message and performs a step over. However when I hover over `UserManager` the popup is: `Microsoft.aspnet.identity.UserManager<porjectName.Models.ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Ok. Do F12/GoToDefinition on "UserManager" in "await UserManager.CreateAsync(...)"when application not running. In default MVC application template, it goes to a property defined in AccountController.cs and its type is "ApplicationUserManager" which is defined in IdentityConfig.cs. So just try to find where it is defined in your case since you said you don't have IdentityConfig.cs. Because if a model is associated with it then you should see a validation too.

Comment: When I perform step-into the popup message is: `Your step-into request in a automatic step-over of a property or operator.
This behavior can be overridden in the context menu for the line being executed by choosing "Step Into Specific" or by unchecking option "Step over properties and operators".` (Step-into shortcut is F11. Did you mean F11 instead of F12)  I have searched `CreateAsync` in entire solution but search returns nothing.

Comment: I mean "Go To Definition". When application is not running if you hover over the object and right click on mouse. You should see "Go TO Definition F12" in it. Click on it.

Comment: ok. I didn't knew it. Thanks. When I F12 on `UserManager` then it goes to line `public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }` inside `AccountController`

Comment: Ok got it. So now in your controller code if you start typing: "UserManager." did the intellisense show you the "PasswordValidator" property? If yes, try setting it to a new instance as shown in my code and check if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91477/discussion-between-siva-gopal-and-irfan-wattoo).

Comment: Thank you for your help.I really appreciate it. +1

Answer (score 0):

@Irfan Yousanif, since you dont have IdentityConfig.cs class, you can write as below my sample code in a sample scenario :

```
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 8, 
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };


        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
```

if you want to remove  entire validation, please comment as below:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            //RequiredLength = 8, 
            //RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            //RequireDigit = true,
            //RequireLowercase = true,
            //RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```